# Infinite loop is occurring. How to fix it?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class reverse {
    private Node head;
    private int listCount;

    public reverse() {
        head = new Node(null);
        listCount = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        reverse obj = new reverse();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, i, x;
        System.out.println("How many no.s?");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter the no.");
            x = sc.nextInt();
            obj.add(x);
        }

        Node newhead = obj.method1(obj.head);
        obj.display(newhead);
    }

    public void add(Object data) {
        Node temp = new Node(data);
        Node current = head;

        while (current.getNext() != null) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }

        current.setNext(temp);
        listCount++;
    }


    public void display(Node newhead) {
        Node current = newhead;
        //System.out.println(current.getNext().getNext().getNext().getNext().getNext().getData());
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.getData() + " " +);
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }

    public Node method1(Node head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return head;
        }

        Node first = head.getNext();
        Node second = first.getNext();

        first.setNext(head);
        head = null;

        if (second == null)
            return head;

        Node current = second;
        Node prev = first;

        while (current != null) {
            Node upcoming = current.getNext();
            current.setNext(prev);

            prev = current;
            current = upcoming;
            //System.out.println(prev.getData());
            //System.out.println(current.getData());
        }
        head = prev;
        return head;
    }

    private class Node {
        Node next;
        Object data;

        public Node(Object _data) {
            next = null;
            data = _data;
        }

        public Node(Object _data, Node _next) {
            next = _next;
            data = _data;
        }

        public Object getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(Object _data) {
            data = _data;
        }

        public Node getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(Node _next) {
            next = _next;
        }
    }
}
```

My `while` statement is not working properly.

Initial value of `newhead.getData()` is 5. The comment part in my code is also giving value as `null` which is correct, but after that there is some error in my `while` loop.

I have written code for reversing a linked list.

`display()` method is to print all the list elements.

Input from user of linked list is:

> 1 2 3 4 5

Output should be:

> 5 4 3 2 1

But my output is:

> null 1 null 1 null 1............occurring infinite times.

Comment: You have a node with data == null. Maybe check for that instead of checking if the node is null

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you post code of `getNext()`? Also based on your output it is possible that you have cycle of your Nodes.

Comment: Your logic in the code seems absurd. Please post the whole code as what you're trying to achieve can't be achieved the way you've coded!

Comment: I have posted my full code of reversing a linked list.... @ shekhar suman

Comment: @user3654181-Your `Node` class seems undefined in the code,please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ shekhar sumanBy changing the condition of while loop of display() method to while(current.getData != null) output is coming accurately. Doing so, is correct or not.

Comment: It  would be nice if we can get your _actual_ code. Since `System.out.print(current.getData() + " " +);` is not valid, I don't think that you're testing with it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Tom I have posted my complete actual code in the question

Comment: Then how  do you test your code, if it can't be compiled? Btw your problem is this line: `first.setNext(head);` in `method1`. After that `first` refers to `head` as its next, which refers to `first` as  its next and that refers back to `head` as its next and so on. This is an infinite "relation" between `head` and `first`.

Comment: @Tom  There is no problem in compilation but the problem is coming after giving all the inputs for the elements of the linked list.                                        i.e. when while loop is running of display() method.                                                                                              Is it right to write first = head ???

Comment: *"There is no problem in compilation"* Then your code in the question is not the code you're really using. *"Is it right to write first = head ?"* If you have a problem with your current algorithm, then take a pen and a paper and write down how _you_ would reverse the list What would you do in each step? Then write that behavior into your program. This mostly helps to find mistakes in an algorithm.

Comment: @Tom okay fine (y). I should work on my code to make it correct.

Comment: @user3654181 That is obivous, that you need work on your code, because you have a problem :P, but you should find the correct algorithm to reverse your list, first. And as I said, it can be easier to write down that algorithm using a pen and paper. For some people, it is easier to understand their assignment/algo to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem when you a filling your data .
all nods have the same reference 
try to print your list

```
    for(int i=;i;list.size();i++)
   System.out.print(list.getObjectAtIndex(i).getData);
```